# Jenkins can not use adb when outside directory

Tags: android, shell, jenkins

As the title says, Jenkins can correctly switch directories to the adb and then execute it. But it can not use it when it is outside of adb's directory.
The following code :

```
.//opt/android-sdk-linux//platform-tools/adb --help
```

results in the following output :

```
+ .//opt/android-sdk-linux//platform-tools/adb
/tmp/jenkins882020622874679741.sh: rad 18: .//opt/android-sdk-linux//platform-tools/adb: Filen eller katalogen finns inte
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

While this code :

```
cd /opt/android-sdk-linux//platform-tools/
ls
./adb --help
```

correctly outputs the adb help manual.
Additionally, entering

```
adb --help
```

gives the same error even when the path given by "which adb" is appended to the $PATH variable.

```
ls /opt/android-sdk-linux//platform-tools/adb
```

also shows that it can see adb from its current directory.

How do I make jenkins run adb without switching directories to the adb directory?

edit 1:

Adding an alias to adb resulted in this error:

```
+ alias adb=.//opt/android-sdk-linux//platform-tools/adb
+ adb shell am instrument -w -r -e debug false -e class se.***** se.*******/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
/tmp/jenkins523172794505644997.sh: rad 24: adb: kommandot finns inte
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working for a while on this I found that Jenkins allows you to inject environment variables in the device configuration. You can also inject environment variables for each build separately. I do not know why exporting them through a bash script does not work but this is what worked for me. In summary, injecting the $PATH variable using Jenkins' built in tool fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, something is still wrong with the PATH inclusion so maybe have Jenkins print the PATH variable to debug. A temporary solution could be using an alias:

$ alias adb=".//opt/android-sdk-linux//platform-tools/adb"

This command will result in **.//opt/android-sdk-linux//platform-tools/adb** being executed every time you execute **adb**.

Comment: That's the problem though. Jenkins doesn't know what to do with .//opt/android-sdk-linux//platform-tools/adb. I added the error message to my edit. The error message is in Swedish though.